# MongoDB - How to add a field to all object within an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, mongodb-update

I have a document with a field called `info`, and info has a field inside it called `data`. `data` is an array of objects. I want to add a new boolean field, `isActive: false`, to each object in data, with **updateMany**.

This is how it looks now

```
{ 
    info: {
        data: [{
                "name": "Max"
            },
            {
                "name": "Brian"
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

This is what I want:

```
{ 
    info: {
        data: [{
                "name": "Max",
                "isActive": false
            },
            {
                "name": "Brian",
                "isActive": false
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: This query is for querying or updating documents?

Comment: @YongShun updating

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the `isActive` field with [all positional operator `$[]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#mongodb-update-up.---).

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "info.data.$[].isActive": false
  }
},
{
   multi: true
})
```

Consider applying `{ multi: true }` if you want to update multiple documents.

Comment: instead of `multi: true` is it possible to use `updateMany`? Because I'm already doing other things using `updateMany`, so I could just put the query within that script?

Comment: If I not mistaken, `.updateMany()` is for Mongoose. The `{ multi: true }` is equivalent to `.updateMany()` in Mongoose. *Because I'm already doing other things using updateMany, so I could just put the query within that script?*, it depends on what is the data and query that you used currently.

Answer (score 1):

UpdateMany is also possible, for example in Compass.

> db.collection.updateMany({"info.data.isActive":{$exists:false}},{$set:"info.data.$[].isActive":false}})